# affix element is flickering when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Try to use [bootstrap affix](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp) plugin in order to fix share buttons section while scrolling

But when scroll down and pass the element, it start flickering.
You can see it here:
http://kohelet.org.il/event/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%92-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A7-%D7%94%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%99

scroll down and look right to the share icons, when `affix-top` should switch to `affix`, something going wrong.

The code I used:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 share">

    <ul class="share-links" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="1020" data-offset-bottom="567">
        <li class="print_page">
            <i class="fa fa-print red"></i>
            <?php if(function_exists('pf_show_link')){echo pf_show_link();} ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope gray"></i>
            <a  class="em" href="" target="_blank">שלח</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-facebook blue"></i>
            <a class="fb" href="" target="_blank">שתף</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter lightblue"></i>
            <a class="tw" href="" target="_blank">צייץ</a>
        </li>
        <li class="w_app_li">
            <i class="fa fa-whatsapp green"></i>
            <a class="wh_app" href="" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">וואטסאפ</a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

And some css:

```
.affix{
    top: 40px;
}
.affix-bottom{
    position: absolute; !important;
}
```

Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `data-offset-bottom="[[affix_bottom]]"` to your `<ul>` . Most likely affix_bottom is somewhere around 1710. You can find it from here. ( I am assuming here that you want to stop the scroll after you main heading finishes.)

```
var selector = '.main-heading-main';
$(selector).offset().top + $(selector).outerHeight(true);
```

You could also try setting your affix-bottom dynamically.